# HP fanfic about two girls who went back in time

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, time-travel, fan-fiction

I'm trying to find a Harry Potter fanfic where two girls (I think one was Hermione, the other might have been Ginny or Luna, not sure) went back in time from sometime during Hogwarts to their younger bodies.

They arrived in the time when they were around age one or two, which chronologically was somewhere around 1980-82. Not sure if before Harry's parents got attacked or after; I think a bit before, but not sure.

In the past, they somehow ended up with a form of magical telepathic communication with each other, which really helped them plan out what they could do (they couldn't really do much otherwise, being stuck in baby bodies). They *might* have ended up so close telepathically that they were almost one mind in two bodies; I'm not sure if they were, but it would certainly explain the following scene better.

At one point several months after their arrival, one (or both) of them is kidnapped and/or experimented on, to create a child for the Malfoy family (aside from Draco, presumably; not really sure why). There is some blood magic involved; for some reason, it backfires, and the result is a third girl that joins their group (shares the telepathy, and I think eventually ends up living with one or both of the original two). That girl had a weird name, but I can't recall what it was.

The fanfic had about a dozen chapters, I think (at least, when I read it, a year or two ago; it might have gotten more since). The scene with the added girl happened in the second half, but not in the last chapter. The whole thing was very humorous, or at least seemed so to me, but I'm not sure if it was actually categorized as humor.

I *think* it was on FanFiction.net, but I'm not entirely sure; might have been somewhere else. I couldn't find it in several online lists of HP time travel fanfics; a few other such lists I found were so long that I didn't check them.

Could any of you find it? I really liked it, and want to read it again (and check if there's any new chapters), but wasn't able to find it in several different search attempts. It's possible that it got deleted, I suppose; if so, sorry.

Comment: This might be a good [start](https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Harry-Potter-Time-Travel-Stories/104249/).

Comment: Thanks! It's not really what I expected, which is probably why I couldn't found it earlier, but it's indeed on that list. (Also hadn't been updated since 2012, sadly.) I'll say more in the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out I was correct that one of the girls was Hermione, but there's a reason that I couldn't recall who the other girl was: it was *also* Hermione. Then there's a third Hermione formed with the Malfoy thing (which was actually earlier than the middle).
Not sure where the telepathic thing came from though.
(Also, sorry for bothering you with something that turned out to be that easy.)

The fanfic, for the record, is [Double Time Trouble](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5137164/1/Double-Time-Trouble), by Skysaber.

(Sadly hadn't been updated since 2012. Also, yes, it's not actually categorized as humor.)

Comment: I remember that one...

Comment: Wound up rereading it, and there's no actual telepathy, but they have "their own language" when young, which adults (particularly those under Confundus) hear as baby babbling, and laster (around the time of the third clone), they literally become of one mind, which they speculate was the result of the Adoption ritual putting the one Hermione in three bodies, and which leads to several "I know what I'm thinking" moments.